# Retrieve a list of children of a unique class given a list of parents

Tags: java, list, filter, collectors

So, Imagine I have a parent Feature class. Then a bunch of children of that class, like Dotted, Stripped, Blank, all inheriting from Feature.

Given a `List<Feature>` I wanna get all objects of that list which are of the Dotted class.

FYI, I first populate the `List<Feature> features` with `features.add(New Dotted())`, `features.add(New Blank())`, `features.add(New Blank())`, etc...

I tried something like that :

```
public List<Dotted> getAllDotted(List<Feature> features){
    List<Dotted> result = features.stream().filter(o -> o.getClass().equals(Dotted.class)).collect(Collectors.toList());
    return result;
}
```

But it doesn't work because the Collector.ToList() won't be converting the result of the `filter()` into a `List<Dotted>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
List<Dotted> d = f.stream().filter(o -> o instanceof Dotted).map(o -> (Dotted) o).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

probably not very clean though.

Comment: Okay, that's working, I've read things about map(), I thought maybe there was something to do with it, but didn't now what.

I'm pretty new to the Java 8 way of querying Lists.

What is not so clean from your POV ?